# how to make json web service in asp.net?

Tags: c#, web-services, json

I m making web service for the first time. and i need to make that using json in c#. I m not getting how to code the methods that fetch data from database
Any suggessions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the below code to return the JSON serialized string:

```
    [WebMethod(Description = "Your Description")]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string FunctionName()
    {           
        // Return JSON data
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string retJSON = js.Serialize(Object);
        return retJSON;

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I spent hours Googling around, trying to find a quick, decent, readable way of creating JSON web services.

In the end, when I'd finally worked out how to do it, I went back and documented it, so I never have to face these hurdles again !!

Have a read [here](http://mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/Services/WebServices-Page1.htm)

(It's actually for WCF JSON web services, but also shows how to link it to a SQL Server database, and so on.)

Comment: Thanks for this, I even enjoyed the "bad joke" section of the tutorial!

Answer (score 3):

Try this [How To Create A JSON Web Service In ASP.NET](http://williamsportwebdeveloper.com/cgi/wp/?p=494)