# c# array like PHP

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to setup the next code in C#

```
'price_changes' => array(
    'color' => array(
        'Red' => '2',
        'Blue' => '-10%',
    ),
    'size' => array(
        'Large'  => '+1',
        'Medium'   => '-3',
    ),
),
```

How do i do this in C# (Winforms)

Or like this:

```
'price_changes' => array(
    'size' => array(
        'Large'  => '+1',
        'Medium'   => '-3',
    ),
),
```

Many thanx for the help.

Comment: Those aren't arrays so much as they are dictionaries.

Comment: Also... in the .Net world, the **types** of your items are extremely important. You don't want to go around setting everything as a string like that. Additionally, instead of a dictionaries or collections of properties, you want to actually define classes for things ahead of time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beside the answer posted by Enigmativity which is more like as PHP code, the following code shows using object-properties to achieve similar structs which could be simpler than using those nested `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string ...` in some situations:

```
var price_changes = new { 
    color = new { Red = "2", Blue = "-10%" }, 
    size = new { Large = 1, Medium = -3 } 
};
```

Usage is so easy:

```
var x = price_changes.size.Large;
```

Comment: How do i pass this object through a webservice in a string[] object?

Comment: It was not mentioned in your question. But, you may use some type of Serialization eg JavaScriptSerializer ... search for it

Comment: I am looking this up for weeks now :S cant find anything :(

Comment: I suggest ask a new question and exactly explain what you want to do

Comment: Also see [this simple code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6210337/2803565)

Comment: The webservice expects a string[] price_changes as a sting array. So sending the Dictionary is setting up a error. When i want to setup a var like: var str = "{'price_changes':['size':{'XL':'+1','4XL':'-3'}}]}"; the error will be in C#: **Cannot impicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[]'** So the output of the object must be a array of strings. Do you understand now?

How do I set the object in C# and pass the new object or the string[] through the PHP web service? I can't change the web service function because it is not changeable.

Comment: Youe php array is called associative array, a special type which is not an array in c#. Recom you to Search (php web service c# Associative Array) or ask new question

Comment: This did the work. How do i start as a null price_changes and then add the color and sizes programmatically:

var price_changes = new { 
    color = new { Red = "2", Blue = "-10%" }, 
    size = new { Large = 1, Medium = -3 } 
};

Comment: Also this does not work: price_changes = new { color = new { Red = "2", Blue = "-10%" }, size = new { 2XL = -10%, Large = 1, Medium = -3 } };

The var does not accepts **2XL** + the **-10%**

Comment: Hi @S.Serp the code above works great. How do i fill the var dynamicly. Just like I say above: The var does not accepts 2XL + the -10%. Do you know how to fill in the var!

Comment: in c#, property/variable names can't be started by a number like 2 in 2XL. for dynamic properties, you may use `ExpandoObject` eg `dynamic x = new ExpandoObject(); x.y="10%"; ...` but i'm not sure if you could use it with your php webservice

Comment: Perfect This is what i want

Answer (score 1):

This would be the C# equivalent:

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>()
{
    {
        "price_changes", new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>()
        {
            {
                "color", new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    { "Red", "2" },
                    { "Blue", "-10%" },
                }
            },
            {
                "size", new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    { "Large", "+1" },
                    { "Medium", "-3" },
                }
            },
        }
    },
};
```

Then if you wrote `var blue = data["price_changes"]["color"]["Blue"];` the variable `blue` would contain `"-10%"`.

Comment: I have to start as an empty var then fill in the size and color. At last the function must resturn and object or a string[] ?

Comment: @Faith - I don't understand your comment and your question. There's no empty `var` here. In C# the `var` is a keyword to tell the compiler to infer the actual type. In this case the variable `data` would have the type `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>`. Are you asking me how to write a function that would return this data?

Comment: Hi @Enigmativity, thanx for the response. In order to save our Products table. The function / webservice expects an string[] or a object from the above function / Dictionary. So i cant return the Dictionary. I mannage to output the Dictionary correct now. But the Dictionary needs to convert to a object or a string[] now?

Comment: @Faith - It is already an object. All things in .NET are. Do you just mean it needs to be serialized into a basic structure that the web service can return?

Comment: YES! Normally it accepts only string[]

Comment: @Faith - That's what you need to ask in your question. How are we to know that? Also, how does a PHP associative array get turned into a `string[]`? Is a single JSON string acceptable. You need to make sure you actually ask what you need in the question.

Comment: Maybe this link is beter to inform: http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/04/20/magento-api-associate-simple-products-to-configurable-or-grouped-product/

I want to add the 'price_changes' object with only sizes.

Comment: @Faith - That link only shows me the PHP code. I can't tell anything else from it.

Comment: This code is used for adding SKU product id's: 'associated_skus' => array('SKU-001', 'SKU-002')

This works fine with the string[] object. But the price_changes var is different. I just don't know how to setup this. 

'price_changes' => array(
        array(
            'color' => array(
                'Red' => '2',
                'Blue' => '-10%',
            ),
            'size' => array(
                'Large'  => '+1',
                'Medium'   => '-3',
            ),
        ),
    ),

Comment: @Faith - Again, that's PHP code. I don't know how that converts to `string[]` so I can't tell you how to do it with C#.

Comment: var price_changes_sizes = new 
{   
color = new { Marine = "-10%" }, 
size = new { L = "1", M = "-3", S = "-10%" } 
};

This works good for the webservice. The question now is how do i generate this dynamically? Anyone??

Comment: @Faith - You need to ask a new question - no-one but me will get notified about your comment. If you ask a new question then it appears on the SO homepage. Also, your original question has been answered. You didn't ask about web services or conversion to `string[]`. Finally, just saying "This works good for the webservice" doesn't say how it works well - show the code of it working - then we have a chance of showing you how a dynamic solution works. Bottom-line: ask a new question.

Comment: @Faith - I just saw the other questions you've asked. I have to say that your questions are not very clear and hence aren't good quality questions. You need to really improve how you ask. Have a read of [ask] and [mcve].